# Convert Tibia OTBM file to Minecraft

Tags: game-development, file-converter

I am new to Minecraft modding but I program for a living and it looks quite simple to get around. I have this fantasy and a quick internet search shows I'm not the only one. For those of you who do not know Tibia is an MMORPG first released in 1997. It is a 2d tile-based game and I would like to see it in 3D. since it is a tile based game it fits nicely with the Minecraft architecture. Tibia is a close-sourced game but there is TibiaOT which is developed by the community and the map file format is OTBM (open tibia binary map). This is a set of 15 2D grids where each grid represents a floor or the height of the grid, the file comes with two more files with monster spawns and default item locations like chests.

There is a Tibia texture pack for Minecraft called "Tibian texture pack", so we got the materials covered. All in all we have the following: a native Tibia map and a Minecraft texture pack.

People have been building Tibia maps manually for years now, it seems stupid because we have a binary file for the real map. What we need is a way to map the OTBM file to a Minecraft map. I am looking for tools to digest the OTBM files into a Minecraft map file.

Comment: -1 [cross](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288936/minecraft-mapping-from-tibia-otbm-file) [site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/88160/minecraft-mapping-from-tibia-otbm-file) [duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/194353/20456), last one was deleted you'll need 10k on Arqade, second last one has been answered using the self answer from the deleted Arqade question

Comment: personally i find the answer on GameDev lacking as i said on Arqade. good answers also help others who have the same problem since as you said *"I have this fantasy and a quick internet search shows im not the only one"*. the answer helps none of those people who share your fantasy

Comment: @Memor-X To be fair this question (the tools part, not the tips part) is on-topic here (unlike SO and Gaming, I don't know about Gamedev). ＠PIRATE Please take more care in the future to post on the right site, and do not post the same question on multiple sites: it's rude to people who do the effort of writing an answer on site 1 only to find that someone had written a similar answer on site 2.

Comment: Thank you, the reason it got on multiple sites is because, i did not know where it should go. apparently Arqade is for people who play games, game dev is for people who develop games and this doesn't seem to fit there. Overflown seems to be more specific src questions.